# TOO MANY REDIRECTS ERROR when redirecting buddypress register page to WordPress sign up

Tags: errors, buddypress, redirect

I have a problem with using Wordpress registration page instead of BuddyPress page, that when I use the [snippets given in github](https://gist.github.com/r-a-y/5578432) and add them to a file named (bp-custom.php) or functions.php file I get an error telling me that there are too many redirects.

I was adviced to remove the second snippet of the link and this removed the error from the page but yet I get an empty buddypress registration page!

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem Found this solution in my intense google search:

```
/ hacks and mods will go here  This Version is plugin folder
/**
 * Disables BuddyPress' registration process and fallsback to WordPress' one.
 */

function my_disable_bp_registration() 
{   
    remove_action( 'bp_init',    'bp_core_wpsignup_redirect' );   
    remove_action( 'bp_screens', 'bp_core_screen_signup' ); 
} 
add_action( 'bp_loaded', 'my_disable_bp_registration' ); 
add_filter( 'bp_get_signup_page', "firmasite_redirect_bp_signup_page");

function firmasite_redirect_bp_signup_page($page )
{
    return bp_get_root_domain() . '/wp-signup.php';   
}
```

Solution:

CHANGE

```
return bp_get_root_domain() . **'/wp-signup.php'**;
```

TO

```
return bp_get_root_domain() . **'/wp-login.php?action=register'**;
```

All is working perfect now

Comment: Duuuudeee .... Sorry for late update! because I did give this a try when you commented on it, and got nothing (because I made a very silly mistake!) ... However, today I decided to give it a try and IT WORKED!!! I really appreciate it, MUCH MUCH thanks ... peace man

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and I have not found a solution except to say I've replicated the same result, using the linked code snippet, with/without the additional snippet, as well as [this version](http://theme.firmasite.com/disable-buddypress-registration-page/).

It's the strangest thing, though, because both version worked out of the box a few days ago when I first tried them, and I only found that the functionality was broken today. This makes me think it's the recent release of either WP 4.4. or latest BP versions which might have broken something.

I'll update this answer as I learn more.